# JSTL cannot parse a double variable multiplied by an integer variable?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

If I set two variables in my controller:

```
double doubleAmount = 18.0;
int integerAmount = 2;
```

And then try to multiply them in my JSTL code:

```
<c:set var="result" value="${doubleAmount} * ${integerAmount}"/>
```

I get this error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: 
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: 
In &lt;formatNumber&gt;, 
value attribute can not be parsed into java.lang.Number: 
"18.0 * 2"
```

How do I perform this operation in my JSTL code?

Answer (score 4):

Try `<c:set var="result" value="${doubleAmount * integerAmount}"/>` please.